# PHP - Decoding data sent from paypal into friendly readable format

Tags: php, paypal

I have a basic php paypal script that works fine (I'm working on sandbox)

my issue is the response I get from paypal is unreadable and cannot therefore be use to do what I want i.e update my database

here's what I'm getting:

```
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC%xxxxx0T
    [BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS] => 0
    [CHECKOUTSTATUS] => PaymentActionCompleted
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d05%2d15T08%3a23%3a58Z
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 16684246
    [EMAIL] => mymail%40gmail%2ecom
    [PAYERSTATUS] => verified
    [FIRSTNAME] => myfname
    [LASTNAME] => mylname
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTONAME] => fname%20lname
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => 1%20Main%20St
    [SHIPTOCITY] => San%20Jose
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [SHIPTOZIP] => 95131
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United%20States
    [ADDRESSSTATUS] => Confirmed
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AMT] => 96%2e00
    .........
```

As shown I'm getting the above response so for instance, I cannot store the timestamp in the database in such format: **[TIMESTAMP] => 2015%2d05%2d15T08%3a23%3a58Z** or email like this: **[EMAIL] => mymail%40gmail%2ecom**

I've tried using utf8 like so:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

but it doesn't seem to help

How can I decode the response I'm receiving from paypal into friendly readable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `urldecode()` function for it.

For example :

```
$data = "mymail%40gmail%2ecom";
echo urldecode($data);
```

Output :

> mymail@gmail.com

Comment: thankyou Jenis..my problem is i was forgetting to decode the response. that works for me.